# Will overwriting an object at its location in memory with another object of the same size cause a memory leak in ARC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, memcpy

I am currently overwriting a constraint with another constraint by directly writing to the space occupied by it in memory. The code is as follows:

```
memcpy((__bridge void*)constraint, (__bridge const void*)constraintClone, malloc_size((__bridge const void *)constraint));
```

(Why I want to do this is explained here: [Intercept/Programmatically set IBOutlet properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921071/intercept-programmatically-set-iboutlet-properties))

So my question is: will this cause a memory leak when utilizig ARC? And if yes, how do I fix it?

Comment: It will try to `release` overwritten pointers so it might even crash. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @grasGendarme I have answered that question in my question. I've been running the code quite a few times now, without any problems. So I don't think that a crash is what will happen (unless there are some rare conditions that need to be met for a crash to occur).

Comment: The 'why' was why would you want to override `IBOutlets` instead of creating and putting the objects on screen from code. The memcpy hack might work, but it's still a hack. Playing with implementation details isn't really future proof, it could change with any iOS minor revision.

Comment: @grasGendarme Precisely that question is answered in the linked SO article. I would happily accept any other solution, however, in that very special case that I have described (in the linked article) I have failed to come up with a better solution. And I'm not interested in putting objects on screen from code, as that would result in 200% more code (or more, as I'm using autolayout). I'm strictly separating UI from code, and I don't want to give up on that principle as I have experienced the "UI in code" nightmare before.

Comment: Sorry, I just read the link in full. If I understand correctly, you replace an object of the same class. That should work fine, since it's the exact same memory layout. You should make sure that the constraintClone has the same `strong` pointers as the original, and everything should work.

Comment: @grasGendarme - There is no "should", at best it is "may work fine". If the opaque object contains a weak reference, and how are you to know, that will break for starters.

Comment: If the object you're overwriting is an Objective-C object managed using reference counting (of either flavor) then you're gonna break stuff big time.

Comment: @grasGendarme - So if I overwrite an object containing a strong pointer to object A with one containing a strong pointer to object B, how will A's reference count be appropriately adjusted?

Comment: @HotLicks I understand he wants to replace a `NSConstraint` with another, referencing the same objects. Shouldn't that be fine? There's no reference count to adjust in that case.

Comment: @grasGendarme - Iffy.  The source object would then have to be deleted, from ARC's viewpoint.

Comment: @HotLicks The source object is deleted, as it's a placeholder view that I "throw away" when replacing it with the "real" view.

Comment: The "source object" is what you're copying FROM.  If that's not properly deleted the counts will get mucked up.

Answer (score 2):

This is not safe.

An object may do things like have a instance variable that's a pointer into its own instance data (for example, it might have an array for a circular buffer, with pointers into that array for the current read and write locations). Such a pointer will continue to point to the source object, not into the destination object.

All of the strong references held by the overwritten object will be lost (leaked). All of the strong references held by the source object will be doubled without a corresponding doubling of the retain counts on the referenced objects. That will lead to eventual over-releases.

Frankly, just consider the "pImpl" idiom and how your approach would wreak havoc with that.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not do this.**

Opaque objects are opaque for a reason and you've no idea what bit copying their memory might do in the general case. At best leaking strongly referenced objects and totally messing up weak references are on the cards.

Avoid the scenario where you need this answer. I've added an answer to your linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921071/intercept-programmatically-set-iboutlet-properties).

HTH